# Why not merge modbus_flush() directly into functions such as modbus_write(read)_xxx() function?

Tags: modbus, libmodbus

I encountered a problem: I created a TCP server with a port of 60000, which broadcasts the data sent to it and can interact with a `modbus RTU` slave. When I use `libmodbus`
When API creates a `modbus RTU over TCP` master station A to connect to port 60000, modbus communication is normal. However, when I use `modbus pull` software to connect to port 60000 using `modbus RTU over TCP`, there will be a situation where both master station A and `modbus pull` data are scrambled. Ultimately, it is determined that this is because either master station A or `modbus pull` received data in their input cache that does not belong to them, If a `modbus_flush()` is added before `modbus_write(read)_xxx()`, this problem can be solved. Then the problem arises.

for example:

```
modbus_flush(ctx);
if (-1 == modbus_write_registers(ctx, addr, count, buf)) {
}
```

Why can't this **modbus_flush()** be directly encapsulated into **modbus_write(read)_xxx()**?  So, every time we go to write or read, the data is always clean?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have two clients connecting simultaneously to a TCP->Serial gateway? If so this would effectively be the same as having two Masters on the serial bus (an unsupported configuration); consider what would happen if the second client sent a request whist a request from the first client was in progress. A better approach might be to use a Modbus TCP->Modbus RTU gateway (the gateway can manage access to the Slave so only one request is in flight at any time). [`MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_LINK`](https://libmodbus.org/reference/modbus_set_error_recovery/) may also help.

Comment: @Brits Yes, you understand correctly, it's because two clients are connected at the same time.